# A countup counter to calculate to a specific number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I,ve a key number like (5) in cell(A1), now i need a formula to calculate and insert number 1 in cell (B1) and increment by one and put them in B2,B3,B4 and B5 then stop.(if i choose other number for (A1) i.e. 27,I,d like B1:B17 filled by 1 to 27

Comment: sorry i mean B1:B27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in B1 enter `1`

From B2 down enter: `=IF(OR(B1="",B1=$A$1),"",B1+1)`
You need to fill down this formula to cover all the numbers you'll likely enter in A1

Comment: Hi mate , ur solution works thx a lot